# Using TidHttp to download Jpeg images from URL (only those that exist)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-7

I am trying to retrieve a large number of images from the web using a TidHttp component.

The problem is that there is a number of images that are missing (Example: 7403, 7412, etc)

How do i test for only those that exist and save those to file?

```
procedure TForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  JPEGImage: TJPEGImage;
  Url, numString: String;
  I, Code: Integer;
begin
 for I := 7400 to 7500 do
 begin
 { 
   Url        :='http://www.mywebpage.com/images/DSC' + numString+  '.jpg';
   try
   idhttp1.Head(URL);
   code := idhttp1.ResponseCode;
   except on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    code := idhttp1.ResponseCode;
   end;//try except
   if code = 200 then
   begin

   MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
   JPEGImage  := TJPEGImage.Create;
   try
     try
     idhttp1.Get(Url, MS); //Send the request and get the image
     code := idhttp1.ResponseCode;
     MS.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
     JPEGImage.LoadFromStream(MS);//load the image in a Stream
     Image1.Picture.Assign(JPEGImage);//Load the image in a Timage component
     Image1.Picture.SaveToFile('C:\Museum_Data\DSC' + numString + '.jpg');
     Application.ProcessMessages;
     except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        code := idhttp1.ResponseCode; // or: code := E.ErrorCode;
     end; //try except
          finally
    MS.free;
    JPEGImage.Free;

  end; //try finally
  end; //if

end;
 end;
```

Comment: as far that I can see you allready do that, if response is 200 go for the picture, but I don't see where numString variable is defined

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to do anything extra for that.  If you try to access a non-existant URL, the HTTP server will report an error that `TIdHTTP` than wraps into an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception.  You do not have to bother with calling `TIdHTTP.Head()` first, since you are downloading the images to a `TMemoryStream` before saving them.  You can catch the exception when calling `TIdHTTP.Get()` by itself, no need to check the ResponseCode at all.

Try this:

```
procedure TForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  MS: TMemoryStream; 
  JPEG: TJPEGImage; 
  Url: String; 
  I: Integer; 
begin 
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    JPEG := TJPEGImage.Create; 
    try 
      for I := 7400 to 7500 do 
      begin 
        Url := 'http://www.mywebpage.com/images/DSC' + IntToStr(I) +  '.jpg';
        MS.Clear;
        try
          IdHTTP1.Get(Url, MS);
        except
          on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do 
            Continue;
        end;
        MS.Position := 0; 
        JPEG.LoadFromStream(MS);
        Image1.Picture.Assign(JPEG);
        JPEG.SaveToFile('C:\Museum_Data\DSC' + IntToStr(I) + '.jpg'); 
        Application.ProcessMessages; 
      end;
    finally
      JPEG.Free;
    end;
  finally 
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You do not actually need the `TImage` in order to save the data to file.  If you can omit the `TImage.Picture.Assign()` stage, then the code a bit simpler by eliminating the `TJPEGImage` altogether (unless you are trying to validate the download files are valid), eg:

```
procedure TForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  MS: TMemoryStream; 
  Url: String; 
  I: Integer; 
begin 
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    for I := 7400 to 7500 do 
    begin 
      Url := 'http://www.mywebpage.com/images/DSC' + IntToStr(I) +  '.jpg';
      MS.Clear;
      try
        IdHTTP1.Get(Url, MS);
      except
        on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do 
          Continue;
      end;
      MS.Position := 0; 
      MS.SaveToFile('C:\Museum_Data\DSC' + IntToStr(I) + '.jpg'); 
      Application.ProcessMessages; 
    end;
  finally 
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure TForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  FS: TFileStream; 
  Url, FileName: String; 
  I: Integer; 
begin 
  for I := 7400 to 7500 do 
  begin 
    Url := 'http://www.mywebpage.com/images/DSC' + IntToStr(I) +  '.jpg';
    FileName := 'C:\Museum_Data\DSC' + IntToStr(I) + '.jpg'; 
    FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
    try
      try
        try
          IdHTTP1.Get(Url, FS);
        except
          on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do 
            Continue;
        end;
        Application.ProcessMessages; 
      finally
        Fs.Free;
      end;
    except
      DeleteFile(FileName);
    end;
  end;
end;
```